How to handle teardown using django-tenant?
I'm using django-tenant and having trouble when i try to create my tests.
I had to create a setup_tenant class to create a teardown before testing, because to access the restaurant table, I had to create the tenant upstream. However, when my tests finish successfully, I get an error during teardown:
ERROR restaurants/tests.py::RestaurantTests::test_update_restaurant - django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "restaurants_restaurant" does not exist
This is the full error:
restaurants/tests.py::RestaurantTests::test_update_restaurant PASSED                                                                                                                                           [100%]
restaurants/tests.py::RestaurantTests::test_update_restaurant ERROR                                                                                                                                            [100%]

======================================================================================================= ERRORS =======================================================================================================
____________________________________________________________________________ ERROR at teardown of RestaurantTests.test_update_restaurant _____________________________________________________________________________

self = <django.db.backends.utils.CursorWrapper object at 0x108b084a0>
sql = 'SELECT "restaurants_restaurant"."id", "restaurants_restaurant"."name", "restaurants_restaurant"."owner_id", "restaura... "restaurants_restaurant"."tenant_id" FROM "restaurants_restaurant" WHERE "restaurants_restaurant"."tenant_id" IN (%s)'
params = (1,), ignored_wrapper_args = (False, {'connection': <DatabaseWrapper vendor='postgresql' alias='default'>, 'cursor': <django.db.backends.utils.CursorWrapper object at 0x108b084a0>})

    def _execute(self, sql, params, *ignored_wrapper_args):
        # Raise a warning during app initialization (stored_app_configs is only
        # ever set during testing).
        if not apps.ready and not apps.stored_app_configs:
            warnings.warn(self.APPS_NOT_READY_WARNING_MSG, category=RuntimeWarning)
        self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
        with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
            if params is None:
                # params default might be backend specific.
                return self.cursor.execute(sql)
            else:
>               return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

This is my Restaurant model:
from customer.models import CustomerTenant


class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="restaurants", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, default="")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tenant = models.ForeignKey(CustomerTenant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="restaurants")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name`

This is my tenant model
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models
from django_tenants.models import DomainMixin, TenantMixin


class CustomerTenant(TenantMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    owner = models.OneToOneField("auth.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="owned_tenant")
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    # Required fields for django-tenants
    auto_create_schema = settings.TENANTS.get("AUTO_CREATE_SCHEMA", True)
    auto_drop_schema = settings.TENANTS.get("AUTO_DROP_SCHEMA", False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Domain(DomainMixin):
    tenant = models.ForeignKey("CustomerTenant", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="domains")
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    is_primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # Support multiple domains per tenant

    def __str__(self):
        return self.domain

    def clean(self):
        # Ensure only one primary domain per tenant
        if self.is_primary and Domain.objects.filter(tenant=self.tenant, is_primary=True).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Only one primary domain is allowed per tenant.")

This is my tests:
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from django.core.management import call_command
from django_tenants.test.cases import TenantTestCase
from django_tenants.test.client import TenantClient
from django.db import connection



from api.models import UserProfile
from order.models import Priority

from .models import Ingredient, Product, ProductFilter, Restaurant, Version

class RestaurantTests(TenantTestCase, APITestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setup_tenant(cls, tenant):
        """
        Add any additional setting to the tenant before it gets saved.
        This is required if you have required fields.
        """
        call_command("createadmin", username="admin", email="admin@example.com", password="password")
        tenant.owner_id = 1
        return tenant
    
    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()
        self.user1 = User.objects.get(username="admin")
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=self.user1, role="owner", restaurant=None)
        
        self.user2 = User.objects.create_user(username="user2", password="password123")
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=self.user2, role="owner", restaurant=None)
        self.client = TenantClient(self.tenant)

        # Log in user1 and get the JWT token
        self.token = self.get_jwt_token(self.user1)
        
        self.client.default_format = "json"

Someone know why teardown can't handle my test ending ?
